What do I need to have set up to have `getblocktemplate` work?
I tried using the command without arguments and it just returned an error code.
Do I need to have some kind of mining software setup? Does that software not already come with Bitcoin Core?
How do I go about getting this software working, either way?

The purpose of getblocktemplate is to return a list of the most profitable mempool transactions and some other data (collectively called a "block template") needed to try and solve the proof-of-work for the next block. This command is used by other software (that doesn't come with Bitcoin Core) that connects to your mining hardware and sends it instructions based on the block templates.
The reason for the error code is that the command requires a JSON parameter with an array field rules with at least the item "segwit":
getblocktemplate '{"rules":["segwit"]}'



Do I need to have some kind of mining software setup? Does that software not already come with Bitcoin Core?

Bitcoin Core does not include a mining capability for mainnet, only for the valueless networks used for testing.
To mine Bitcoin, you need to purchase mining equipment based on ASICs.

You can definitely use Bitcoin Core to generate mainnet block templates, which is what the question is about.

@VojtěchStrnad thanks, yes, but I was addressing the second paragraph specifically. "Does that [mining software] not already come with Bitcoin core". Quotation prefixed to answer to clarify this.
